# how to compare two row in the same table but where column less than and greater than number

Tags: mysql, database, select

I want to create a random select query where `records` compare each other within the same table based on `bid` column. The difference between should 50 number of comparison between `bid` column?

**For Example**

```
select query should be select only 400,350,375 these `bids` in the range of 
`50` number? now it is showing only 400 and 350 records?
```

**Database Records**

[image]

**Select Query**

```
SELECT a.bid, a.uid 
FROM wp_auction_bids a inner join wp_auction_bids b
ON ABS(a.bid - b.bid) = 50
WHERE a.pid='1626';
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: i want to create a random select query where bid column less than and greater than 99 and 100 it should be compare with same table

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us what is the expected result output ?

Comment: from where is that pid comes?

Comment: I want to create a random select query where `records` compare each others within the same table based on `bid` column. The difference between should 99 and 100 number of comparison between `bid` column?

Comment: still waiting for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve the problem?

```
SELECT bid, uid FROM wp_auction_bids WHERE bid >= 99 AND bid <= 100 AND pid=2 Limit 3;
```

Comment: which means there is no bid record between 99 and 100

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood about the question, you might need an inner join.

Try this:

```
    SELECT a.bid, a.uid 
    FROM wp_auction_bids a inner join wp_auction_bids b
    ON abs(a.bid - b.bid) = 50
    WHERE a.bid >= 99 AND a.bid <= 100 AND a.pid=2 
    Limit 3;
```

Comment: but i want records only where 50 difference between bid column?

Comment: You can then just =50 instead of >=50

Comment: I have used the `=50` now records `400` and `350`  are showing but not getting `375` why? `50` is the range

Comment: because 375 is not 50 away from any other value; it is 55 away from 320; so I was using >=50, so you cld get those 4 values.

Comment: but `375` will be in the `50` range

Comment: now I'm using `>=50` now same records are repeating in the result?

Comment: SELECT a.bid, a.uid 
    FROM wp_auction_bids a inner join wp_auction_bids b
    ON ABS(a.bid - b.bid) >= 50 and ABS(a.bid - b.bid) <= 55 
    WHERE a.pid='1626'  why it is showing `45` bid in the record?

Comment: please check the database screenshot

Comment: to check which bid it got matched with, add b.bid to select clause

Comment: SELECT b.bid
    FROM wp_auction_bids a inner join wp_auction_bids b
    ON ABS(a.bid - b.bid) >= 50 and ABS(a.bid - b.bid) <= 55
    WHERE a.pid='1626'
    now  it is showing `100` bid also

Comment: I meant ... SELECT a.bid, a.uid ,b.bid  FROM wp_auction_bids a inner join wp_auction_bids b ON ABS(a.bid - b.bid) >= 50 and ABS(a.bid - b.bid) <= 55 WHERE a.pid='1626'

Comment: see the value of b.bid...so u know how a.bid is coming (hte 45 value)...accordingly you can adjust the where clause